# Honda Nighthawk 250 oil does not rise to the cam lobes

Tags: honda, oil

I have a Nighthawk 250 model 1993.
I have the problem that the oil not rise to the cam lobes of left cylinder.
My actions:
1. Change the oil pump to a new one. Works fine
2. Check the little orifice on motor to connect the right cylinder oil channel to the left. Is OK

The right cylinder received a very good flood of oil on the head and cramshaft.

Any idea? Thanks

GPA